# Period $2$ solutions of $N_{t+1}=rN_t(1-N_t)$

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How do you show that the discrete difference equation below has non-trivial solutions of period $2$ for only $r>3$?

$$N_{t+1} = rN_t(1-N_t) $$

Period $2$ solutions satisfy:

$$N_{t+2}=N_t \text{ for all } t$$

and $$ N_{t+1} \ne N_t $$

I found that $N_{t+2} = rN_{t+1}(1-N_{t+1})=r(rN_t(1-N_t)[1-rN_t(1-N_t)]$ but I don't see how this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions for the equation (I use $N \equiv N_t$)

$$
N_{t+2} = r( rN (1-N))(1-rN(1-N)) = N
$$
since it's 2-periodic, are:

$$
N = \frac{\pm \sqrt{r^2-2r-3} + r + 1}{2r},\\
N = (r-1)/r
$$

The $N = (r-1)/r$ doesnt fit (it's 1-periodic), and since $r^2-2r+3 = (r+1)(r-3)$, it has real solutions for only r > 3.

Comment: Where does the line with +- come from?

Comment: Just a regular quadratic equation.

Comment: It just seems like you've pulled a derren brown trick on me, I don't see where it comes from at all, I get stuck on the line $-r^3N^3+2r^3N^2-(r^2+r^3)N+r^2-1=0$ from $N_{t+2}=N$

Comment: @StevenCr99 Indeed the writing of the solution is slightly odd (but then why accept it on the spot?). Note that $N=0$ and $N=(r-1)/r$ being solutions of $N=f(N)$, one knows beforehand that they are also solutions of $N=f(f(N))$. Hence $N$ and $N-(r-1)/r$ both divide the degree $4$ polynomial $f(f(N))-N$, leaving one with a degree $2$ polynomial, whose roots one can find by the well-known discriminant formula.

Comment: Is that assuming $r>0$? Thanks for reply Did

Comment: yes, if $r<0$ is allowed, than possible 2-periodic solutions appear at r $< -1$ (as you can see from my answer: with $r > 3$ and $r < -1$ the determinant is positive and the solutions are real values)

Comment: thanks for the help, can i ask why can't the discriminant be zero? eg $ r=3$ if that is a trivial solution then why?

Comment: If $r=3$ than $N_t = 2/3, N_{t+1} = 3 \cdot 2/3 \cdot (1- 2/3) = 2/3$, which is 1-periodic